# How does it come that a soda still sparkles out of the bottle, even after I can squeeze it allready?

Tags: pressure

Just noticed this right now.

I have known for long time that of course, shaking a sparkled soda causes it to harden and build up pressure.

When one now carefully opens the bottle it starts to release this pressure. At some point I can squeeze the bottle again (slightly opened bottle), without any additional increase of soda, except of course those due to displacement. But then, when I open it slightly more it starts sparkling out again.

So, how does this come? Is this because pressure is not the only force taking place here?

Comment: "Of course" is not that obvious. I think the hardening only occurs with a bottle that has been opened recently. Can you please clarify what you do and what you observe? How full is the bottle? What things have happened to the bottle since you bought it? What do you mean exactly by "increase of soda" and "sparkling"?

Comment: @Han-KwangNienhuys: I'm talking about PET(dunno if thats the international acronym aswell) bottles. So they are made of pretty soft plastic. The state I described with "ofcourse" was, that the sparkling is building up some pressure(or what ever is the source for it) when its shaked. This event can best be observed for an original sealed bottle. And it is assumable that it had been shaken heavily before, but I can't exactly know, as this is just emphirical. and in increase of soda I mean the "water line" that is going up.

Comment: Then get a new, unopened bottle, let it stabilize (temperature and pressure) for at least four hours, then describe step by step what you do and see. If possible, post a video on youtube.  Don't forget to mention the temperature and the type of soda (sugared, light, mineral water). I'll repeat your steps and try to explain it.

Comment: @Han-KwangNienhuys: OK, thats what I'm going to do this evening. I'll update my post after finishing the "experiment" (Thats by definition what one would call so, isn't it?)